# Removing ActionBar

Tags: android

I'm looking forward to removing the ActionBar of a certain activity by changing the styles name value to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar,but all that's doing is making the ActionBar disappear across all other Activities.Please Help!

Comment: please describe more and provide your manifest

Answer (score 0):

in the android manifest file find your particular activity and use Theme like this

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```